# differences between value_counts() and apply(pd.value_counts)

Tags: pandas

The following field contains three values, incremental, full, and differential, and `value_counts()` and `apply(pd.value_counts)`

Why there is such differences?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is problem you need apply function `Series.value_counts` to aomecolumns of `DataFrame`, so use `apply`.

It is same as:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.value_counts())
#same as
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an undocumented method:

```
Signature: pd.value_counts(values, sort=True, ascending=False, normalize=False, bins=None, dropna=True)
Docstring:
Compute a histogram of the counts of non-null values.

Parameters
----------
values : ndarray (1-d)
sort : boolean, default True
    Sort by values
ascending : boolean, default False
    Sort in ascending order
normalize: boolean, default False
    If True then compute a relative histogram
bins : integer, optional
    Rather than count values, group them into half-open bins,
    convenience for pd.cut, only works with numeric data
dropna : boolean, default True
    Don't include counts of NaN

Returns
-------
value_counts : Series
```

If you passed your column as the arg then the output is the same as `pd.Series.value_counts`:

```
In [8]:
Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType
df = pd.DataFrame({'Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType': [0,1,1,2,np.NaN], 'val':np.arange(5)})
df

Out[8]:
   Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType  val
0                                0.0    0
1                                1.0    1
2                                1.0    2
3                                2.0    3
4                                NaN    4

In [9]:
pd.value_counts(df['Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType'])

Out[9]:
1.0    2
2.0    1
0.0    1
Name: Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType, dtype: int64

In [10]:    
df['Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType'].value_counts()

Out[10]:
1.0    2
2.0    1
0.0    1
Name: Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType, dtype: int64
```

however when you `apply` the method, you're doing this for every element so the returned Series is trying to align this on the original df, in effect you get a 2-D array:

```
In [7]:
df['Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType'].apply(pd.value_counts)

Out[7]:
   0.0  1.0  2.0
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  1.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Here the values are the columns and the indices are the same as your original df